# CloudKit "subscription is duplicate of" error - get SubscriptionId

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckquery, ckerror

I'm trying to save a `CKQuerySubscription` to the public database - a `CKError` is returned with the following information:

```
[
    "ServerErrorDescription": subscription is duplicate of 'C82E82EF-F373-4D75-A465-65364D8FEB12',
    "CKErrorDescription": Error saving record subscription with id E30DB4D5-2617-4E0D-8CFE-A14538140029 to server: subscription is duplicate of 'C82E82EF-F373-4D75-A465-65364D8FEB12',
    "NSDebugDescription": CKInternalErrorDomain: 2032,
    "NSUnderlyingError": <CKError 0x1c064ec70: "Server Rejected Request" (2032); server message = "subscription is duplicate of 'C82E82EF-F373-4D75-A465-65364D8FEB12'"; uuid = A5290A31-650C-44FC-B1C1-7BCB181291F8; container ID = "iCloud.com.mycompany.myapp">, 
    "NSLocalizedDescription": Error saving record subscription with id E30DB4D5-2617-4E0D-8CFE-A14538140029 to server: subscription is duplicate of 'C82E82EF-F373-4D75-A465-65364D8FEB12', "errorKey": ck1uc5yob, 
    "RequestUUID": A5290A31-650C-44FC-B1C1-7BCB181291F8, 
    "ContainerID": iCloud.com.mycompany.myapp
]
```

The properties `ancestorRecord`, `clientRecord` and `serverRecord` on the `CKError` object are all `nil`.

How can I get the ID of the query that exists on the server from this error (ie `C82E82EF-F373-4D75-A465-65364D8FEB12`). Is there a property that I'm missing that would have it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options. I tend to use `fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletion` handler to pull all subscriptions and then parse the ones I'm interested in, like so:

```
 [publicDatabase fetchAllSubscriptionsWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray<CKSubscription *> * _Nullable subscriptions, NSError * _Nullable error)
 {  
     for (CKQuerySubscription *sub in subscriptions)
     {
         NSString *predString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sub.predicate];
     }
 }];
```

But you can also use [CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckfetchsubscriptionsoperation?language=objc) to pull all subs, or specific subs based on the subscription ID. In this case, you'd create the operation, configure the subscription ID you're interested, add your post-processing code to the completion block, and then run then run the operation.

Comment: Yeah, I've gone with configuring the subscription ID for the moment, but for my case it's not an idea solution..